# MVC 3, ModelMetadata weird behavior during navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelmetadata

One of the properties in my model is decorated with `Hide` attribute. When I load a page this property is not displayed (as expected). When I click "Back" and then "Forward" buttons, essentially navigating away and then back, then this property shows. When I do a refresh then property is hidden away. Why?

Model is rendered via custom edit template.

Comment: Could it be a "cache" problem?

Comment: Can you show come code and give a little better explanation of what's happening?